# how to turn off the loop of audio loop in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I tried to build an alert app and it can notify twice.

First notification just play the sound once and second play repeats of the sound.

I import the sound use the `webpack`:

```
import audio from '../file/sound.mp3';
```

and call this file in my constructor

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    timeIsComing: false,
    timeIsUp: false,
  }
  this.audio = new Audio(audio);
}
```

the function of in the `timeInterval`

```
countDown(){
 if(timeIsComing){
  this.audio.play();
 }
 if(timeIsUp){
  this.audio.addEventListener('ended', this.playSounds.bind(this), false);
  this.audio.play();
 }
}
```

the `playSounds()` function:

```
playSounds(){
 this.audio.currentTime = 0;
 this.audio.play();
}
```

I set a reset function to initialize the alert.

But when I reset and count the timer second times, the state of `timeIsComing` become `true` and the sound will play in unlimited loop.

my reset function:

```
reset(){
 this.setState({timeIsComing: false, timeIsUp: false});
 this.audio.removeEventListener('ended', this.playSounds.bind(this), false);
 this.audio.pause();
}
```

Is there way to turn off the repeats?

**UPDATE**

Demo At CodePen [two times alert App Demo](https://codepen.io/Hiphopkiddz/pen/MQgKpo)

Comment: Do you think you could make an example on codesandbox or something similar, or maybe the full code. We can't see how you are calling these functions so can't be really much help.

Comment: Okay maybe build an demo is good idea. In my question I just want to know how to remove event listener to let the sound repeats can be turned off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're passing different functions in your addEventListener/removeEventListener calls.

You should bind your `this.playSounds` function like this :

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    timeIsComing: false,
    timeIsUp: false,
  }
  this.playSounds = this.playSounds.bind(this);
  this.audio = new Audio(audio);
}
```

and then you can just do :

```
this.audio.removeEventListener('ended', this.playSounds, false);
```

same thing for `addEventListener`. Binding in the attach/remove of the event will create a new function. So when you try to remove it, it will not find that function.